# Do you use the indicative mood in an if-clause and the subjunctive mood in a main clause?

Tags: grammar

Please look at the first sentence in the following passage. Do you sometimes use this kind of sentence? That is, the indicative mood in an if-clause and the subjunctive mood in a main clause?

> If you currently add up the electoral votes of those three states, you 
>   would have 96 electoral votes. Even if a candidate won North Dakota, 
>   South Dakota, Montana, Wyoming, Vermont, New Hampshire. Connecticut and 
>   West Virginia, they would only gain 31 electoral votes total from those 
>   eight states. Here is where it can get a little tricky. On a rare 
>   occasion, like in the year 2000, someone can win the popular vote but 
>   fail to gain 270 electoral votes. This means that the winner may have won and collected their electoral votes by small margins, winning just enough  states with just enough electoral votes, but the losing candidate may 
>   have captured large voter margins in the remaining states.
>
> > [Does your vote count? The Electoral College explained - Christina Greer](https://ed.ted.com/lessons/does-your-vote-count-the-electoral-college-explained-christina-greer)

Answer (score 1):

It is very common. The "would" is forming what is sometimes called the "present conditional" and the indicative is now more common than the subjunctive in the "if" clause.

It is very common to use a conditional tense in the main clause, especially when discussing events that may be unreal.